# Does Python have the Elvis operator?

Tags: python, conditional-operator, elvis-operator

The ternary operator in many languages works like so:

```
x = f() ? f() : g()
```

Where if `f()` is truthy then `x` is assigned the value of `f()`, otherwise it is assigned the value of `g()`. However, some languages have a more succinct [*elvis* operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elvis_operator) that is functionally equivalent:

```
x = f() ?: g()
```

In python, the *ternary* operator is expressed like so:

```
x = f() if f() else g()
```

But does python have the more succinct *elvis* operator?

Maybe something like:

```
x = f() else g() # Not actually valid python
```

Comment: Undoing the dupe-close because this is *not* asking for null-coalescing behavior. (Also, the accepted answer on the old dupe target is bug-prone and terrible.)

Answer (score 48, accepted):

## Yes

Python does have the elvis operator. It is the conditional `or` operator:

```
x = f() or g()
```

`f()` is evaluated. If truthy, then x is assigned the value of `f()`, else x is assigned the value of `g()`.

Reference: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elvis_operator#Analogous_use_of_the_short-circuiting_OR_operator

Comment: YES I could not find anywhere that "elvis operator" was mentioned, but this is functionally equivalent. Thank you.

Comment: And I've never heard of "elvis operator" before.

Comment: If you interpret `?:` as a smiley, the curl of the question mark resembles Elvis' emblematic hairstyle.

Comment: This is not equivalent of Elvis operator, which is *ternary* operator while `or` is binary operator. Meaning: you can't decide if call `f()` or `g()` depending on some other condition `h()`.

Comment: @Cromax, you seem to be conflating the Elvis operator (`a ?: b`) with the ternary operator (`c ? a : b`). They are not the same thing. See, for example, https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elvis_operator

Comment: @Robᵩ Heck, you're right, I had this wrong all the time. :-)

Comment: There is a problem with `or` operator: it returns the right expression even if the left one is not `None` but equals to `0`. The purpose of elvis operator is to perform strict null/nil/undefined/None checks. Every language has logical OR operator but some of them also provide elvis operator or alternative (like ?? in JS)

Comment: @lem0nify - you seem to be describing the [null-coalescing operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_coalescing_operator), which has the behavior you list. On the other hand, the [Elvis operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elvis_operator) is based on truthiness, not existence. Regardless, OP is clearly asking for a truthiness operator. `or` describes perfectly what the OP is looking for.

Answer (score 14):

**NB** Python does **not** have the *null-coalescing* operator defined by:

```
a if a is not None else b
```

The `or` operator in `a or b` checks the truthiness of `a` which is `False` when `a==0` or `len(a)==0` or other similar situations. See [What is Truthy and Falsy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39983695/what-is-truthy-and-falsy-how-is-it-different-from-true-and-false)

There is a proposal to add such operators [PEP 505](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0505/)

Comment: OP specifically asked about checking `a` for truthiness, not checking `a is not None`.

Comment: @CrazyChucky Hmm, I may have fudged the distinction between the elvis operator and the null-coalescing operator. Nevertheless I'll leave this answer up for others who may have the same confusion.

Comment: Good point, I think it's worth pointing out. Perhaps mention specifically that the Elvis and null-coalescing operator are similar, but have this distinction?

Comment: @CrazyChucky Edited. I'll point out that some languages, like Kotlin, use `?:` for null-coallescing and Wikipedia actually has sections for both behaviors under ["elvis operator"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elvis_operator#Object_reference_variant) and in examples has entries for '??' as well. So the term is not exactly clear-cut.

Answer (score 0):

[Robᵩ's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48813117/108326) about using `or` is a good suggestion. However, as a comment to the original question,

```kotlin
x = f() ? f() : g()
```

is functionally equivalent with

```kotlin
x = f() ?: g()
```

only if `f()` has no side effects.

If, for instance, `f()` reads from a stream or generator, calling it twice will have different results than calling it once. Rewriting slightly to Python syntax, the following sample

```python
values = (x for x in (1, 2, 3))
def f(): return next(values)
def g(): return 42
x = f() if f() else g()
print(x)
```

will print 2, while `x = f() or g()` would print 1.

It might be better to state the question as

```kotlin
tmp = f()
x = tmp ? tmp : g()
```

or, in Python,

```python
tmp = f()
x = tmp if tmp else g()
```

or in Python 3.8 and up,

```python
x = tmp if (tmp := f()) else g()
```

Both of the latter two examples are equivalent with

```python
x = f() or g()
```

regardless of any side effects `f()` might have.

Answer (score -3):

```
>>> a = [1,2,3]
>>> b = [4,5,6]
>>> c = [4]
>>> a + (b,c)[b>c]
[1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> a + (b,c)[b<c]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
>>>
```

Python elvis operation is

```
(testIsFalse, testIsTrue)[test]
```

The Java equivalent is

```
test ? testIsTrue:testIsFalse
```

Comment: That's not what the elvis operator does. You're thinking of the ternary operator.