# None propagation in Python chained attribute access

Tags: python, method-chaining, null-coalescing-operator, null-coalescing

Is there a **null propagation operator** ("null-aware member access" operator) in Python so I could write something like

```
var = object?.children?.grandchildren?.property
```

as in C#, VB.NET and TypeScript, instead of

```
var = None if not myobject\
              or not myobject.children\
              or not myobject.children.grandchildren\
    else myobject.children.grandchildren.property
```

Comment: Related: [Does Python have the Elvis operator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48813097/does-python-have-the-elvis-operator), [Is there a Python equivalent of the C# null-coalescing operator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4978738/is-there-a-python-equivalent-of-the-c-sharp-null-coalescing-operator)

Comment: @smci, OP is specifically asking about chained attribute access. There may well be a duplicate for that, but I don't think it's the one you've proposed.

Comment: @Chris: ok please retitle, retag and reword accordingly. (The original title was merely *"null/None propagation in Python"*)

Comment: @Chris: the question title couldn't be understood without reading the body b) it has no tags by which it would be found by search. This can cause duplicates in future.

Comment: @smci, we're getting in the weeds here. The question has already been improved by your edits and somewhat less by mine. Let's not argue about what it originally _was_. I'll see if I can find additional tags for it.

Comment: Thank you guys for the edits. I considered adding a #null-propagation tag but it was specific to C# and i don't have enough rep for creating a new, more generic one. That being said, I've got the answer I was looking for,  and I hadn't found before using SO search.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

No. There is a [PEP proposing the addition of such operators](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0505/) but it has not (yet) been accepted.

In particular, one of the operators proposed in PEP 505 is

> The "`None`-aware attribute access" operator `?.` ("maybe dot") evaluates the complete expression if the left hand side evaluates to a value that is not `None`

Comment: Is it still not implemented in 2023?

Comment: @SaeedNeamati, correct. PEP 505 is deferred, meaning "Inactive draft that may be taken up again at a later time".