# One liner to "assign if not None"

Tags: python, python-3.x, null-coalescing-operator

Is there a way to do an assignment only if the assigned value is not None, and otherwise do nothing?

Of course we can do:

```
x = get_value() if get_value() is not None
```

but this will read the value twice. We can cache it to a local variable:

```
v = get_value()
x = v if v is not None
```

but now we have made two statements for a simple thing.

We could write a function:

```
def return_if_not_none(v, default):
    if v is not None:
        return v
    else:
        return default
```

And then do `x = return_if_not_none(get_value(), x)`. But surely there is already a Python idiom to accomplish this, without accessing `x` or `get_value()` twice and without creating variables?

Put in another way, let's say `=??` is a Python operator similar to the [C# null coalesce operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-coalescing-operator). Unlike the C# `??=`, our fictional operator checks if the right hand side is `None`:

```
x = 1
y = 2
z = None

x =?? y
print(x)   # Prints "2"

x =?? z
print(x)   # Still prints "2"
```

Such a `=??` operator would do exactly what my question is asking.

Comment: `value()` is a function, not a value. Is it right?

Comment: What about `x = value() or x`  It is just as verbose as `x = value() if value()` but only executes value() once.   https://stackoverflow.com/a/48813117/2193968  https://stackoverflow.com/a/4978745/2193968

Comment: @SangbokLee  I don't think so.  Look at the links I provided.

Comment: I rewrote slightly to make it clear.

Comment: @JerryJeremiah yes, but it accesses x twice

Comment: This question is under specified. Do you mean *assign if x is falsy*, do you mean *assign if x is `None`*, do you mean *assign if x has not previously been assigned a value*, or is it something else? Python doesn't have a null.

Comment: @RyanHaining I mean: Assign if `get_value()` is not `None`, do nothing otherwise.

Comment: @Donentolon  Does `x = value() or x` really access value() twice?  It doesn't look like it but python could do anything internally...

Comment: @JerryJeremiah It can presumably access `x` twice if `value()` is None: Once to read, once to write. Perhaps there is some optimization, but the point is that `x` is written twice in the source code.

Comment: @JerryJeremiah doesn't really matter, because OP only cares about `None`, so if `value()` returns empty string, 0, or any other false value, it won't work.

Comment: @Donentolon  Sorry I didn't realize that your question wasn't about actualy running the get_value() function twice but rather about having neither x no get_value() visible in the source code more than once.  That's not clear in your question at all.  When I read the question I understood it to ask how to avoid running the get_value() function more than once with code on a single line.

Comment: `x = value() or x` will assign `x = x` if `value()` is `None`. But OP wants 'do nothing' if `value()` is `None`. We need whatsoever `if` here.

Comment: @RyanHaining  The question was edited after I made all those comments.  I guess I could delete them...

Comment: @SangbokLee  And the answer already posted doesn't do that either but it has upvotes....

Comment: `name = expr if expr is not None` is not valid. Do you mean `if expr is not None: name = expr`?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

In python 3.8 you can do something like this

```
if (v := get_value()) is not None:
    x = v
```

Updated based on Ryan Haining solution, see in comments

Comment: Does that really assign 1 to x if value() returns null?  Shouldn't it assign x to x so that the value remains unchanged?

Comment: I assumed that should be some value that we will assign in case when `value()` returns `None`. But if we have to restore x value this will not work

Comment: `if (v := get_value()) is not None): x = v`

Comment: It will introduce additional variable, I thought question was about avoiding this.

Comment: OP has mixed requirements, another seems to be that they don't want to rewrite `x`. Your proposal works easily when the value of `x` is known when writing the code, but if it were dynamic, you'd have to store `x`'s old value before possibly overwriting with `value()`.  Further, you want `is not None` because OP also only cares about ignoring `None`, not all falsy value.

Comment: Still doesn't answer the question the OP actually wanted to ask (including the part about not mentioning any variable more than once and not creating new ones) but it is a GOOD answer and has my upvote.

Comment: Python 3.8 one liner: x = v if (v:=get_value()) is not None else x

Comment: Although, this may give some error in linters "undefined-variable", so we can invert the condition to `x = x if (v:=get_value()) is None else v`

Answer (score 1):

You can also just use the `or` operator if you want something neater.

In your example:

```py
x = 1
y = 2
z = None

# x =?? y
x = y or x
print(x)   # Prints "2"

# x =?? z
x = z or x
print(x)   # Still prints "2"
```

Of course, order of variables matters here, and you have to be careful, since

```py
x = x or y
```

Is meaningless if x is not `None`, and might even throw an exception if `x` was never defined before.

Comment: `x = x or y` will assign `y` to `x` if `x` evaluates to `False`. This means that if `x` is `0`, it will take the value of `y`. It's not just checking whether `x` is `None`