# How to create if-else statements on dicts with missing keys

Tags: python

I want to create an if-else condition on dictionaries with missing keys. Such that, if the key is missing then append the value `None`, otherwise append the data when it exists.

However, this approach would stop with an error as when the key does not exist it seems to not return `True or False`.

For example:

```
df = [{'data':'test', 'videos':5, 'likes':4}, {'data':'test','likes':4}]
videos = []
for i in df:
    if i['videos']:
        videos.append(i)
    elif i['videos'] is not True:
        videos.append('None')
```

Output:

```
{'data': 'test', 'videos': 5, 'likes': 4}
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
/var/folders/dr/9wh_z8y10fl79chj86pq7knc0000gn/T/ipykernel_3180/3991749010.py in <module>
      1 df = [{'data':'test', 'videos':5, 'likes':4}, {'data':'test','likes':4}]
      2 for i in df:
----> 3     if i['videos']:
      4         print(i)
      5     elif i['videos'] is not True:

KeyError: 'videos'
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Return None if Dictionary key is not available](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6130768/return-none-if-dictionary-key-is-not-available)

Comment: You can use this https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just check if the key is actually in `dict.keys()`

```
df = [{'data':'test', 'videos':5, 'likes':4}, {'data':'test','likes':4}]
videos = []
for i in df:
    if 'video' in i.keys():
        videos.append(i)
    else:
        videos.append('None')
```

Comment: This works great! a few issues with the code output but I managed to reconfigure it to my needs. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I would go for a list comprehension using `.get()` method of Python's dictionaries as this one would return `None` by default if the requested key is missing:

```
df = [{'data':'test', 'videos':5, 'likes':4}, {'data':'test','likes':4}]

videos = [e.get("videos") for e in df]
```

Comment: Output `[5, None]` as expected?

Comment: @hc_dev yes, indeed.

Comment: I don't think this is the desired output.

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR:** Use the *defaulting* getter [`dict.get(key, default)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get) like  `videos.append(i.get('videos', 'None'))`.

#### Lookup by key in a dict

string-indexing a dict entry will always raise `KeyError` if the key was not found.

Use the safe `dict.get(key)` method which returns `None` as default if key is not found.

See also: [Why dict.get(key) instead of dict[key]?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11041405/why-dict-getkey-instead-of-dictkey)

#### Make your code simpler and robust

Your if-statement could be simplified to:

```
video = i.get('videos')   # use a safe get by key
videos.append(video if video else 'None')  # if not found, then default string
```

The construct `x if condition else y`  is called [*conditional expression*](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#conditional-expressions) ([*ternary operation*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary_operation#Computer_science)) - not to confuse with [*Elvis operator*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elvis_operator): [Does Python have the Elvis operator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48813097/does-python-have-the-elvis-operator/48813117#48813117)

Just for the completeness to catch and handle a `KeyError` is also an option:

```
try:
    video = i['videos']   # unsafe may raise KeyError
except KeyError:
    video = 'None'  # default
videos.append(video)  # after the try-except the video is guaranteed to have a string
```

See the Python tutorial: [Try and Except in Python](https://pythonbasics.org/try-except/)

Comment: @KellyBundy Thanks for proof-reading and the clarification to learn. Added links and fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Ah ... now I understood. You just want to filter the list for items that contain 'videos' ?!

Maybe use the [`filter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter) function.
See my demo on interactive Python shell:

```
>>> df = [{'data':'test', 'videos':5, 'likes':4}, {'data':'test','likes':4}]
>>> list(filter(lambda i: i.get('videos') is not None, df))
[{'data': 'test', 'videos': 5, 'likes': 4}]
```

Note: the return of `filter` is a filter-object which needs to be converted using `list()`.